# Assigning a Static Public IP to Azure App Service using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I am currently deploying an ASP.NET Core Web API on Azure App Service and I need this service to utilize a static public IP address. The reason behind this requirement is that there is a 3rd party integration which necessitates IP whitelisting.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_web_app

Moreover, I also plan to deploy the same ASP.NET Core Web API in Azure Container Registry (ACR) and leverage Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) for orchestration. I mention this in case it impacts the process of assigning the static public IP to the Azure App Service.

### Edit

I created a simple App Service using Terraform code:

```
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "asp" {
  name                = "${local.basename}-asp"
  resource_group_name = module.resource_group.name
  location            = var.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app" {
  name                = "${local.basename}-app"
  resource_group_name = module.resource_group.name
  location            = var.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.asp.id

  site_config {}
}
```

[image]

Does that mean that if I whitelist all of these IP addresses in Binance's API key, it's going to be okay? Just to clarify, if I wanted to have a single outbound IP address, then I would have needed NAT Gateway, right?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#get-a-static-inbound-ip

Comment: @silent, thanks for that! Looks like this is getting a list of all outbound IP addresses which I can whitelist? Is that correct? As long as these IP address will not change ever, then I'm fine with it.

Comment: @silent, I was looking at some other posts, but they're creating `azurerm_virtual_network`, followed by `azurerm_public_ip`, subnet, etc. But it looks like creating a virtual network and subnet is meant to be used in cases where you have two applications and you want both of them to use the same IP address?

Comment: "When can an inbound IP change?" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#when-inbound-ip-changes   Using a public IP with an App Service is not a supported scenario. If you really want a single public IP that you can control, I suggest you rather look at AKS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard#specify-the-load-balancer-ip-address

Comment: @silent, I might test all solutions, so I know what the pros and cons are. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-nat-gateway does this work for App Service as well?

Comment: oh wait, you are talking about outbound IP address?! I assumed we are talking about inbound

Comment: @silent, Just to clarify, if I wanted a static public IP for accessing my service, that's inbound. And if I wanted a static IP for making outbound connections, that's outbound? If so, for inbounds I would use Application Gateway (or Front Door) and for outbounds a NAT Gateway?

Comment: @nop, did you get this working? I'm looking at something similar so I'll be looking to make a Terraform file based from https://cloudblogcenter.com/2022/06/05/configure-static-outbound-ip-address-for-azure-app-service/#:~:text=Search%20for%20%E2%80%9CNAT%20gateway%E2%80%9D%20and,used%20for%20virtual%20network%20integration.

Comment: @MaxPower, sorry for the late reply. Yes, I did. Will post it as an answer.

Comment: No problem @nop, I'm just as bad. I managed to work it out in the end but it's good to see you've done it a similar way :) I didn't use the "swift" connection however but a normal one and its all good. I tried a similar thing for Cloud Service (ES) however it didn't use the outbound IP as I think due to them being associated to a load balancer, but I need to confirm that!

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less what I did to achieve what I needed. Additionally, I've broken it down into modules as it's best practices, but for the sake of simplicity of this answer, I would keep it that way.

```
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "asp" {
  name                = "${local.basename}-asp"
  resource_group_name = module.resource_group.name
  location            = var.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "S1"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app" {
  name                = "${local.basename}-app"
  resource_group_name = module.resource_group.name
  location            = var.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.asp.id

  site_config {
    vnet_route_all_enabled = true # WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL
  }

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "${local.basename}-vnet"
  resource_group_name = module.resource_group.name
  location            = var.location
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "snet" {
  name                 = "${local.basename}-linuxapp-snet"
  resource_group_name  = module.resource_group.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]

  delegation {
    name = "delegation"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_nat_gateway_association" "example" {
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.snet.id
  nat_gateway_id = azurerm_nat_gateway.ng.id
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pip" {
  name                = "${local.basename}-pip"
  resource_group_name = module.resource_group.name
  location            = var.location
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_nat_gateway" "ng" {
  name                    = "${local.basename}-ng"
  resource_group_name     = module.resource_group.name
  location                = var.location
  sku_name                = "Standard"
  idle_timeout_in_minutes = 10

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_nat_gateway_public_ip_association" "association" {
  nat_gateway_id       = azurerm_nat_gateway.ng.id
  public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.pip.id
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "example" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_linux_web_app.app.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.snet.id
}
```